# $x^{1997}-1=0$ probability for its root sum to be larger or equal to certain irrational number

Tags: probability

I am look at a problem relating to Roots of unity and probability
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1997_AIME_Problems/Problem_14

the problem is as follows:

[image]

and frankly speaking I'm having a hard time understanding the solutions, especially the third one.

For example, [here how the x was derived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/951qX.png) and also how to get the number 332 in the following paragraph.

may someone help explain or come up with another solution

Comment: That solution omits a quadratic in $y$ from the left-hand side of one circle equation. This is a typo, of course. Until you work out what it should be, you will remain confused.

Comment: @J.G. but even with y^2 added, shouldn't it be (2+sqrt(3))/2? I'm so confused.

Comment: The $x$ is what you've found, but $v = (x-1) + yi$.  Normally, I'd assume this was the result of multiple authors shifting the graphs horizontally by $1$ and not compensating elsewhere, but it looks like the entirety of solution 3 has been unchanged since its addition on the 23 Feb 2017.  It's just not been fixed since then.